# Using `NSCache` object which doesn't conform `NSDiscardableContent`?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, caching

I read doc about `NSCache`. Documentation says objects conforms `NSDiscardableContent` will be removed on insufficient memory situation. Does the class behave on classes which don't conform `NSDiscardableContent` protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. NSCache behaves as I expected.